# Spring aspectj annotation pointcut

Tags: java, spring, aop

I was trying to create an Aspectj pointcut on method annotation but I failed all the time with different approaches. I'm using aspectj autoproxy (I have no other weaving configured in my spring context). My classes look like this:

```java
public interface Intf
{
  @SomeAnnotation
  void method1() throws SomeExc;
}

public class Impl implements Intf
{
  @Override
  public void method1() throws SomeExc
  {
    //...
  }
}

@Aspect
public class MyAspect
{
  @AfterThrowing(
    pointcut = "execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(SomeAnnotation)",
    throwing = "error")
  public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint jp, Throwable error)
  {
    System.err.println(error.getMessage());
  }
}

@Component
public class Usage
{
  @Autowired
  Intf intf;

  public void doStuff()
  {
    intf.method1();
  }
}
```

So I'm wondering why the aspectj won't create the pointcut. I managed to make it work using `execution(* *(..) throws SomeExc)` which does the job for me but I still want to know what I did wrong.

Also since `method1` is defined in an interface and I specify the annotation on implementing class, is there a way to make it work this way? Other proxying mechanisms like transaction management/security works this way in other parts of spring right? And if I'm using interface proxying would specifying the pointcut on implementing class create the pointcut? (I guess not since I'm not using cglib)

Comment: Try to use full package path define your aop annotation expressing.

Comment: Yep I tried that if you mean using `@annotation(full.class.path.SomeAnnotation)` in my pointcut definition. But thanks anyway ;-)

Answer (score 3):

try to add @Component to MyAspect class

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
...
```

Comment: Thanks I tested this but still no go. What is your reasoning behind this? To allow spring use annotation based configuration for this class? I thought aspectj is handling aspects on its own. And other configuration (setting the throws field) works like charm. To be clear I'm initializing the aspect as a bean using class name in my spring context MXL.

Comment: I thought the beans are annotated with @Component so you're using component scan, so why MyAspect is different. Anyway, the bad news is that it worked on my side, otherwise i wouldnt post the answer, but theres no way to know why it works here but doesnt work there.

Comment: In this case I don't need component scanning since I'm initializing the bean via complete class name nor do I need more complex bean configuration via annotation so (from what I know which isn't much since I'm fairly new to spring) why doing that (based on documentation for `@Component` this annotation is only useful if I'm using component scanning and/or annotation configuration). 

One thing to note: I'm using custom project setup not Maven, could there be a problem. (Not using maven is a historical decision which I wouldn't repeat from now on ;-) )

Comment: I agree, when the same piece of code works in one environment and fails in another evnironment, that means theres a difference in environments :)

Comment: lol indeed, Spring doesn't consider the `@Aspect` as a component without `@Component` annotation

Answer (score 3):

simply mark your aspect method with

```
@After("@annotation(package.SomeAnnotation)")
```

Have a look at [this](http://rdafbn.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/intercept-annotation-with-aspetcj-in.html) for a step by step guide